# How do I get a taller header image in this ghost theme?

Tags: css, ghost-blog, ghost

Please take a look at this Ghost theme: https://github.com/wbkd/ghost-wbkd

Can't figure out how to increase the height on the header image. Changing the header height doesn't help. I think it's just being overdrawn. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Needed to sleep on it. Add a margin-bottom to #header .taglist-wrapper in webkid.css